# error: definition of implicitly-declared ‘constexpr DistanceTotale::DistanceTotale(const DistanceTotale&)’

Tags: c++

I have an error when i don't compile with the standard C++11, and I don't undestand why. There is my .hpp :

```
#include <vector>

#ifndef VOYAGEUR_HPP
#define VOYAGEUR_HPP

class DistanceTotale {
    protected:
        int M;
        double * dist;
    public:
        DistanceTotale(int M0) : M(M0), dist(new double[M0*M0]) {}
        DistanceTotale(const DistanceTotale & D);
        double distance(int i, int j) const { return dist[i+M*j]; }
        double & distance(int i, int j) { return dist[i+M*j]; }
        double operator()(const std::vector<int> & x) const;

};



#endif
```

And my .cpp :

```
#include "voyageur.hpp"

DistanceTotale::DistanceTotale(const DistanceTotale & D) : M(D.M), dist(nullptr) {
    dist = new double[M*M];
    for(int i = 0; i<M*M; i++) {
        dist[i] = D.dist[i];
    }
}
```

I have the following error :

> voyageur.cpp:11:56: error: definition of implicitly-declared
>   ‘constexpr DistanceTotale::DistanceTotale(const DistanceTotale&)’

For the line :

```
 DistanceTotale::DistanceTotale(const DistanceTotale & D) : M(D.M), dist(nullptr) {
```

Comment: You are missing a semicolon in your c'tor. It should be ```DistanceTotale(int M0) : M(M0), dist(new double[M0*M0]) {};```. With that small addition it works fine for me (initialize an object and then create another object using copy c'tor)

Comment: It seems like the compiler do not accept the copy ctor declaration. You don't any preprocessor definitions? I can only reproduce the error by removing the copy ctor declaration of D in the header file. That's the only reason I can see or that you are including the wrong header file.

Comment: Thank you, it was the semcolon @Roim, so it was after C++11 that we don't need it.